# Why is the return object by document.getElementById different from $(".class").last().get()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I don't get why the difference (using 1.9.1):

```
document.getElementById("myId").children;
```

outputs an array of DOM elements

But if I do:

```
$("#myId").get().children;
```

outputs `undefined`
Why?

jQuery .get() documentation says:

> .get() method grants access to the DOM nodes underlying each jQuery object

so why are the children empty if the DOM node with the id=myId has children?

Plus if I do `$("#myId")[0].children` I get the same result as with the first method (getElementById). Shouldn't get() do the same?

Comment: Just a thought, but `console.log(document.getElementById('myId').children, $('#myId').get().children);` would have answered your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because `.get()` returns an array.

```
$("#myId")[0].children
```

or use .prop() like

```
$("#myId").prop('children')
```

[.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get2)

> Retrieve the elements matched by the jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

Missing index

[.get( index )](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

```
$("#myId").get(0).children;
```